# convert a sql queries into the django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
View 
def group_codes(self):
    final_shelves = self.final_shelf_info()
    stbrole_codeInfo = ResultsTestsCodes.objects.filter(
        results_test_id=self.kwargs['testID'],
    ).values('build').annotate(
        script_fail = Sum('script_fail'),
        script_total = Sum('script_total'),
        post_testing_fail = Sum('post_testing_fail'),
        post_testing_total = Sum('post_testing_total'),
        mr_fail = Count('stb_role'),
        gw_fail = Count('stb_role'),

    ).order_by(
        'build',
    )

    return stbrole_codeInfo
```

Module

```
    from django.db import models


class ResultsTestsCodes(models.Model):
    results_test_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    build = models.CharField(max_length=401)
    tr_codes_id = models.IntegerField()
    pair_no = models.IntegerField()
    stb_names = models.CharField(max_length=1600)
    build = models.CharField(max_length=41)
    pre_testing_pass = models.IntegerField()
    pre_testing_fail = models.IntegerField()
    pre_testing_total = models.IntegerField()
    script_pass = models.IntegerField()
    script_fail = models.IntegerField()
    script_total = models.IntegerField()
    post_testing_pass = models.IntegerField()
    post_testing_fail = models.IntegerField()
    post_testing_total = models.IntegerField()
    stb_role = models.CharField(max_length=2)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'results_tests_codes'
```

Template

```
 Total failed details:<br />
<b>------------------------</b> <br />
{% for code in group_codes %}
    *_{{ code.build }}_*<br />
    {% if test_info.test_type = 0 %}
        {{ code.pre_testing_fail }}/{{ code.pre_testing_total }} failed pre-test<br />
    {% else %}
        {{ code.mr_fail }}/{{ code.script_total }} 
        <span>MR</span> failed during script<br />
        {{ code.gw_fail }}/{{ code.script_total }} 
        <span>GW</span> failed during script<br />
        {{ code.mr_fail }}/{{ code.post_testing_total }} 
        MR failed during post-test<br/>
        {{ code.gw_fail }}/{{ code.post_testing_total }}
         GW failed during post-test<br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<br /><br />
```

I am trying to count failed mr and gw and write this results on my template.

```
{{ code.mr_fail }}
```

I would like to convert this query into the django, but not too sure how I can achieve it.

```
SELECT script_fail, stb_role FROM results_tests_codes
WHERE results_test_id = 10787
AND script_fail = 1 AND stb_role = "M"
```

and {{ code.gw_fail }}

```
SELECT script_fail, stb_role FROM results_tests_codes
WHERE results_test_id = 10787
AND script_fail = 1 AND stb_role = "G"
```

Any helps, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT script_fail, stb_role FROM results_tests_codes
WHERE results_test_id = 10787
AND script_fail = 1 AND stb_role = "M"

results = ResultsTestsCodes.objects.filter(results_test_id=10787, script_fail=1, stb_role='M').values('script_fail', 'stb_role')
```

and

```
SELECT script_fail, stb_role FROM results_tests_codes
WHERE results_test_id = 10787
AND script_fail = 1 AND stb_role = "G"

results = ResultsTestsCodes.objects.filter(results_test_id=10787, script_fail=1, stb_role='G').values('script_fail', 'stb_role')
```

Then you can access `script_fail` and `stb_role` like this:

```
for result in results:
    print(result.get('script_fail'))
    print(result.get('stb_role'))
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! @nik_m. This was exactly what I was looking for.